# Dynamic data for Adapter attached to EditText

Tags: android, autocomplete, adapter, android-edittext

Is there a way to attach dynamic adapter to EditText?

What I want is - when a key is pressed on EditText, my code to do a search in (some) custom store and provide suggestions (instead of static Xml-list or array). This store is not a database; I think CursorAdapter is for database results only. Example code snippets are welcomed.

Comment: couldn't you use a simple ArrayAdapter?

Comment: the data in store changes over time as the user uses the application. New objects are added and these new objects much be available in the auto-complete list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and posted the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542219/dynamically-update-autocomplete-box-in-android).

Write a custom `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Override `runQueryOnBackgroundThread()` method and return a new MatrixCursor based on the input contraint. Associate this adapter to the autocomplete editbox.

I got the hint for this answer @ http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/