# How to remember typed text in SearchView?

Tags: android, searchview

After typing some text in SearchView and closing keyboard the text deletes in SearchView, I want to typed text remain.

Comment: please explain briefly what you are trying to do?

Comment: See this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542219/dynamically-update-autocomplete-box-in-android

Comment: @ Ram kiran, I use SearchView, and I want to search text after typing remain in SearchView, not disappear.

Comment: I solve this problem with searchView.setQuery(query,submit) in onCreateOptionsMenu, where query I get from intent.

Comment: @Shrikant,  thanks, but I think I don't need AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: (1) In the `onQueryTextSubmit()` of `OnQueryTextListener`, you can save it in a field. (2) Then restore the query using `searchView.setQuery("query text", false);` from the field (by setting a `OnClickListener` on your `SearchView` (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14809924/1276636))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the getText() method and retrieve the text. Or you can use the OnTextChanged event Listener to retrieve the text as it is typed.