# Nullpointerexception when trying to add SearchView to my appcompat activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar, searchview, appcompatactivity

I am getting Nullpointerexception when trying to add SearchView to my appcompat activity.I have already gone through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832890/android-nullpointerexception-on-searchview-in-action-bar) but couldn't resolve it.

Here is my

**menu_main.xml**

```
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:title="Search"
              android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

**onCreateOptionsMenu**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
```

I also tried:

```
mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
```

**Getting Below exception:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(boolean)'
>   on a null object reference

Comment: you edit your manifest.xml too?

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos I added `<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33400808/6176003

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos already checked ..i used app:actionViewClass only

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

            searchView = new SearchView(this.getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.
                        getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

             @Override
             public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                 // collapse the view ?
                 //menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).collapseActionView();
                 Log.e("queryText",query);
                 return false;
             }

             @Override
             public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                 // search goes here !!
                 // listAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                 Log.e("queryText",newText);
                return false;
             }


            });

        }
```

Comment: Its not crashing.but not getting callbacks..onQueryTextChange,searchClose

Comment: @varmashrivastava i update my code with searchview listener try it and tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is Working

**menu.xml**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

**Java Code:**

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sol_menu, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setIconified(false);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: not working for me..                                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setIconified(boolean)' on a null object reference