# SearchView Suggestion doesn't work with one character

Tags: android, searchview

I have a problem with my `SearchView` Suggestion, when I write one character in the `SearchView` the Suggestion doesn't come.
But when I write two characters in the `EditText` of my `SearchView` the Suggestion will come.

So I want that my Suggestion already come when I write one character in the `EditText` of my `SearchView`, what can I do?

My Code from MainActivity:

```
private SearchView mSearchView;
private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> mList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mList.add("Test 1");
    mList.add("Test 2");
    mList.add("Test 3");
    mList.add("Test 4");
    mList.add("Test 5");
    mList.add("Test 6");
    mList.add("Test 7");
    mList.add("Test 8");
    mList.add("Test 9");
    mList.add("Test 10");

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.suggestion, null, new String[] {""}, new int[] {R.id.suggestion_textView}, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mAdapter);

    // onItemClick
    mSearchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position)
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position)
        {
            // Only for Test
            finish();
            return false;
        }
    });

    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s)
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s)
        {
            final MatrixCursor c = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { BaseColumns._ID, "" });

            for (int i=0; i < mList.size(); i++)
            {
                    c.addRow(new Object[] {i, mList.get(i)});

            }
            mAdapter.changeCursor(c);
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found a solution myself. It's not clean but it will work.
I have debug into `SearchView` and then I found the ID of the `AutoCompleteTextView` from `SearchView`. Than I set the Threshold for the `AutoCompleteTextView` from 2 to 1. Now it works.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    // Solution
    int autoCompleteTextViewID = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    AutoCompleteTextView searchAutoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) mSearchView.findViewById(autoCompleteTextViewID);
    searchAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
    ///////////

    mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mAdapter);

    // onItemClick
    mSearchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position)
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position)
        {
            // Only for Test
            finish();
            return false;
        }
    });

    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s)
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s)
        {
            final MatrixCursor c = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { BaseColumns._ID, ""     });
            for (int i=0; i < mList.size(); i++)
            {
                if (mList.get(i).toLowerCase().startsWith(s.toLowerCase()))
                {
                    c.addRow(new Object[]{i, mList.get(i)});
                }
            }
            mAdapter.changeCursor(c);

            return false;
        }
    });
return true;
}
```

Comment: If you're using appcompat the id should be `getResources().getIdentifier("search_src_text", "id", getPackageName())`

Comment: If you're using appcompat you can also directly reference the `R.id.search_src_text`

Comment: @user3747780 You are my favourite person