# Using SearchView on ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-activity

So I am trying to create a simple activity page that shows all contacts. Using the search view in the action bar, they should be able to filter the contacts. The contacts are correctly being populated into the ListView but the SearchView is not filtering the list. The list never updates.

This is my contacts activity:

```
package com.example.android.whereyouat;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class Contacts extends AppCompatActivity {

    Cursor cursor1;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    SearchView searchView;
    ListView lv;
    MenuItem searchMenuItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        startManagingCursor(cursor1);

        String[] from = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};
        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, cursor1, from, to);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setChoiceMode(lv.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_contacts, menu);
        searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);

        SearchManager SManager =  (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchViewAction = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
        searchViewAction.setSearchableInfo(SManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchViewAction.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_search:
                //openSearch();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your action of filtering is handled by `adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);` return true.

Comment: @SamidhT thanks for responding but I just changed it and that didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: can you also post code of your filter method in adapter class?

Comment: @SamidhT this is all the code I have for this activity. I was following a tutorial where the person was able to filter it this way. The only problem was they used listadapter instead of simplecursoradapter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24279952/1461078 check this

Comment: I still have the same problem @SamidhT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89870/discussion-between-user3645858-and-samidh-t).

Comment: see [this](https://codeshare.io/aFQT7) it uses `EditText` instead of `SearchView` but the logic of `filter()`ing is EXACTLY the same

Comment: @pskink search view doesnt support addTextChangedListener. What should be the substitute for searchview?

Comment: `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`