# How to use SearchView widget "without" support v.7 library

Tags: android-actionbar, android, searchview

So according to [developer.android documents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView), this is how one can include a SearchView in ActionBar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

The official guide, have only covered the SearchView from the support library, and not the one from Android Framework.

However, I am certain that my users have Android 4+ devices, so I want to use SearchView without appending support library to my app.

**What changes should I make to my ActionBar XML menu layout?**

I could not find any other tutorial on SearchView without Support Library.

Comment: Heres the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of **[SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.html)**:

> **Note**: This class is included in the support library for compatibility with API level 7 and higher. If you're developing your app for API level 11 and higher only, you should instead use the framework SearchView class.

It basically means that you use the SearchView class from the android.widget package and set the minSdkVersion to 11 in your manifest or build.gradle.

**Update** based on the comment I just removed the *yourapp** namespace. This should probably work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

You can visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar) SO post for more information.

Comment: I know this, but my question is how? what in the XML should be changed? Please red my question once again.

Comment: @Campiador this link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar