# Android: finish activity when perform a search on SearchView

Tags: android, android-search

I have a simple searchview to perfom search functions and but I want when someone search something to finish the current activity where the searchview is placed and add and a Transition effect and then open the activity with the results. But I can't find a way to do it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good starting guide here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html. This one here is a bit more advanced: [Implementing SearchView in action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar).

Answer (score 0):

you can override the `startActivty(Intent intent)` method in your activity which has searchview.

```
@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
    finish();
    super.startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom, R.anim.abc_slide_out_top);
}
```

It worked for me. :)