# Search Field causes app to crash

Tags: android, search

I'm writing an app which is playing music (and movies later). I added some menu items like shuffle, repeat song, exit etc. and all works like a charm. But I can't get the search button working (to search for requested song name). Here are errors from log cat when I used debugger, entered app and clicked the magnifying glass/search button:

[LogCat](http://wklej.org/id/1498714/)

Comment: post your code for reference?

Comment: Here are the fragments of code where search button is used [link](http://wklej.org/id/1498747/)
I tried to add this function using this tutorial
[link](http://antonioleiva.com/actionbarcompat-action-views/)

Answer (score 0):

//global declaration

```
public SearchView mSearchView;
```

//try this in setup searchmethod

```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // action bar items
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.moj_media_play, menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
               |MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
               mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItem.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
        return true;

    }
```

//onoptionsitemSelected

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_rand:
              mojMedPl.setShuffle();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Odtwarzanie losowe włączone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
              break;
        case R.id.action_end:
              stopService(playIntent);
              mojMedPl=null;
              System.exit(0);
              break;
        case R.id.action_repeat:
             mojMedPl.setRepeat();   
            // if(mojMedPl.checkRepeat=true)
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Powtarzanie włączone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            // else     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Powtarzanie wyłączone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
              break;
        case R.id.action_search:
             mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

            // mSearchView.setIconified(false); 

             return true;

        }
        return false;
        //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for help, I did what You posted but still crashes at the same time (when clicking on magnyfying glass)

Comment: [refer to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar)