# SearchView like Inbox app

Tags: android, android-view

Google's new Inbox app has a new SearchView. It is full screen with search suggestions (based on previous searches and common search phrases) with top results sections. Take a look at a screenshot:

[image]

Now I want to know is this a Android SDK standard view? Is it a support library (v21) view?
If yes, do you know a good tutorial on how to use it?
If no, do you know an available open source view like this?

If I want to implement this view, what is best approach? Creating another Activity when user clicks on Search button? opening a custom dialog? any idea?

Comment: It's a standard SearchView,  have you tried this?

Comment: Did you manage to achieve it? I've been looking around for this too

Comment: that's definitetly not the standard SearchView, I'm looking for an implementation too. my current approaches are going in the way of showing a new activity or displaying a fragment over the activity

Answer (score 1):

This may be the easiest approach to deal with this problem
[Implementing SearchView in action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar) you can develop the layout like inbox app.