# How to add a search view on action bar tabs just same as in play store application

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, searchview

I want to add a search view on action bar tabs my tabs has custom list view. Just same as play store application please tell me ho to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing SearchView in action bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) which shows how to add searchview