# How to get data from server when i enter something in search box like auto search?

Tags: android, search, server, searchview

i trying to implement auto search mechanism in android like google. Here when i enter some words then display related search results in list view. For example i entered 3 letters then display related search results from server, again i will add another letter to previous 3 letters then automatically display related search results with out click search button.I don't know how to do it, every time api calling. How to use Search view option from android xml for searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On client side you should with the help of `AutoCompleteTextView`, `Adapter`, `HTTPClient` and other stuff you handle sending a request to server. On server side you implement `Filter` after querying database. After filter is done - respond result and via `AutoCompleteTextView` you show suggestions. Then via `Adapter` you set list.

[Very nice example](http://makovkastar.github.io/blog/2014/04/12/android-autocompletetextview-with-suggestions-from-a-web-service/)

Now when you know which way to search better use google. It is rich on that kind of info and if you face some problems - ask new question with exact! problem.
hope it is helpful.

Comment: how to use search view?

Comment: take a look at this answer. very nice example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar. Your questions are too broad you should narrow it.

Comment: Boss i tried that sample, but when i type something in that edit text, it will display properly, but when i click that search result display one popup, how to do that???

Comment: it is very hard to talk about features when no code. make a skeleton and when (if!) you face this or another issue post an exact question with code what you have done and I'm sure Community will correct it for you.