# search in an listview using a Searchview on the action bar

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, searchview

i have an activity that list clients on a listview from a sql server database, and i've had implement the searchview.. but i dont know how to implement the query to search the client names from the listview.. can someone help me??

here is my the code from the activity where is the list:

```
package com.example.hp13_b200.testedesign;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;



public class listar_clientes extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ListView list;
    private TextView nome, abv, esaldo, telefone, mail, morada;
    private SearchView search;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_listar_clientes, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;


        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView


    }








    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://ciemarco.dyndns.org:90/androidapp/listar_clientes.php";

    // JSON Node names

    private static final String TAG_CLIENTE= "clientes";
    private static final String TAG_NOME = "nome";
    private static final String TAG_ABV = "nome2";
    private static final String TAG_SALDO = "esaldo";
    private static final String TAG_TELEFONE = "telefone";
    private static final String TAG_MORADA = "morada";
    private static final String TAG_MAIL = "email";




    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listar_clientes);

        // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        /*if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            doMySearch(query);
        }*/


        nome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        abv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.abv);
        telefone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.telefone);
        morada = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.morada);
        mail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mail);
        esaldo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.esaldo);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
        //  Log.v("COUNT-->",productsList.get(0).toString());
        // Get listview




  /*   list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem

                String nome = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText()
                        .toString();
                Log.d("Cod_conta: ", ""+nome);
                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(listar_clientes.this,
                        detalhes_cliente.class);
                // sending pid to next activity

                in.putExtra(TAG_NOME, nome);
                //in.putExtra(TAG_ABV, abv);

                Log.d("entrou: ", "vai entrar");
                //startActivityForResult(in,100);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivity(in);
            }


        } );*/


        // launching Edit Product Screen
//        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
//
//
//                // Starting new intent
//                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
//                        list_item.class);
//                // sending pid to next activity
//                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
//
//                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
//                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
//            }
//        });

      /*  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                encomendas_user.this, productsList,
                R.layout.activity_list_item, new String[] { TAG_IDUSER,
                TAG_TITULO},
                new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
        // updating listview
        setListAdapter(adapter);*/
        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }



    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(listar_clientes.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("A Carregar dados. Por favor Aguarde...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                //  int success = json.getInt(TAG_IDUSER);
                //Log.d("NAMSUCCESSE: ", ""+success);
                //if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CLIENTE);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);


                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NOME);
                    String abv = c.getString(TAG_ABV);
                    String telefone = c.getString(TAG_TELEFONE);
                    String morada = c.getString(TAG_MORADA);
                    String mail = c.getString(TAG_MAIL);
                    String esaldo = c.getString(TAG_SALDO);



                    Log.d("NAME TESTE: ", name);
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_NOME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_ABV,  abv);
                    map.put(TAG_TELEFONE, telefone);
                    map.put(TAG_MORADA, morada);
                    map.put(TAG_MAIL, mail);
                    map.put(TAG_SALDO, esaldo);



                   // if(UserInfo.userID==(Integer.parseInt(name))){
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                   // }


                }
              /*  } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                           // NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                   // startActivity(i);
                }*/
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            listar_clientes.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.activity_list_item_clientes, new String[]{TAG_NOME, TAG_MAIL, TAG_TELEFONE, TAG_MORADA, TAG_SALDO},
                            new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.mail, R.id.telefone, R.id.morada, R.id.esaldo});
                    // updating listview
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);



                }
            });

        }







    }

    public void  listar(View v){
        LinearLayout vwParentRow = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();

        TextView nome=(TextView)vwParentRow.getChildAt(1);

        TextView telefone=(TextView)vwParentRow.getChildAt(4);
        TextView morada=(TextView)vwParentRow.getChildAt(3);
        TextView mail=(TextView)vwParentRow.getChildAt(5);
        TextView esaldo=(TextView)vwParentRow.getChildAt(6);



        // Starting new intent
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                detalhes_cliente.class);
        // sending pid to next activity
        in.putExtra(TAG_NOME, nome.getText().toString());

        in.putExtra(TAG_TELEFONE, telefone.getText().toString());
        in.putExtra(TAG_MORADA, morada.getText().toString());
        in.putExtra(TAG_MAIL, mail.getText().toString());
        in.putExtra(TAG_SALDO, esaldo.getText().toString());


        // starting new activity and expecting some response back
        startActivityForResult(in, 100);
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem item= menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
        item.setVisible(false);
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and here is the code from the searchresultactivity:

```
package com.example.hp13_b200.testedesign;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class SearchResultsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
        handleIntent(getIntent());

    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        handleIntent(intent);
    }
    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            //use the query to search your data somehow
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search_results, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Model-View-Controller approach, all you need to do is create a model with the data that matches your search and hand it tho the view (your list view) that will display it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a `setOnQueryTextListener` which can filter your results when text is written in `SearchView`.

There is an existing post explaining this quite well, [Implementing SearchView in action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar).