# app bar with view following fragment edge

Tags: android

How to build App Bar like in Gmail app?

That is when Navigation Drawer is
A/ collapsed
B/ expanded
"search icon" [belonging to fragment with emails list] is following right edge of fragment.

See below images for cases A and B.

Assume using AppBar stuff from Android 5, for example:

- Toolbar
- AppBarLayout
- CoordinatorLayout

[image]

[image]

Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Your app has several elements in it. I will guide you to the pages you need to search for to get the necessary answers to complete your project.

To implement the search function in the app bar, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22302422/1116216) will definitely help you. I have never done it myself, but I am sure you will find your answers in that post.

To implement the rest of the screen, I would choose a combination of a Master/Detail Flow activity, together with a Navigation drawer. So when creating the project I would choose a Master/Detail flow as the main activity (part of the Android Studio samples), and add the following code to it:

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        // displaying count
        // check whether it set visible or not
        if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
            txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
        }else{
            // hide the counter view
            txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: has this answer helped you? If yes please accept and upvote.