# How to hide action bar on clicking search menu item and display when search is done?

Tags: android

I've an action bar and three tabs each includes some list to display. 
When I click search I want the rest of the action bar should be hidden except the list in a tab and search item it self should be enabled, where want to search.

How can I achieve it?

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<!-- Single menu item 
     Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
-->

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

<item android:id="@+id/home"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_home"
    android:title="Home" />

<item android:id="@+id/totalCash"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_delivered"
    android:title="Cod" />

<item android:id="@+id/statusForEach"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_cancelled"
    android:title="Status" />

<item android:id="@+id/logout4"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_cancelled"
    android:title="Logout" />

<!--<item android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_delete"
    android:title="Delete" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_preferences"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_preferences"
    android:title="Preferences" />-->
```

Comment: cant understand your requirement....can you please elaborate?

Comment: Can you post your xml?

Comment: visit here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar

Comment: I've Edited my question by providing xml @Yashasvi

Comment: Implement  MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener, to listen to the events when the search bar expands/collapses. Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

add below line to all menu items except search

```
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

and in your search item add

```
    app:iconifiedByDefault="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement [MenuItemCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener.html) interface to get those events. that will allow you to listen open and close and many more events. so check it.

Comment: I used the same. But here I'm having events on search like onQueryTextSubmit or onQueryTextChange. But question is on click on search I want to hide entire action bar except search  and list. Just like whatsapp.