# Handling on click listeners with custom suggestion item

Tags: android, onclick, android-search, search-suggestion

I'm including a search view following the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar). I've created a custom suggestion item which includes a text and an ImageButton. The important code is below:

**Filter Activity**, in this class the search view is been initialize, and I have the OnQuery Listeners.

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
    {
        if (Utils.isQueryOk(query))
        {
            ....
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
    {
        if (newText.length() > 1)
        {
            new getSuggestionsFromServer().execute(newText);
        } 

        return true;
    }
});

private class getSuggestionsFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    List<String> suggestions;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        // Retrieve suggestions from server

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "text" };
        Object[] temp = new Object[] { 0, "default" };

        MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columns);

        for(int i = 0; i < suggestions.size(); i++)
        {
            temp[0] = i;
            temp[1] = suggestions.get(i);

            cursor.addRow(temp);
        }

        SearchManager manager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        final SearchView search = (SearchView)mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search).getActionView();

        search.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position)
            {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position)
            {
                // This is not getting called!

                Log.d(TAG, "SuggestClick: " + search.getSuggestionsAdapter().getCursor().getString(1));

                return true;
            }
        });

        search.setSuggestionsAdapter(new SuggestionAdapter(FilterUI.this, cursor, suggestions));
        search.getSuggestionsAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

} /* [END getSuggestionsFromServer] */
```

**SuggestionAdapter class**

```
public class SuggestionAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{
    private List<String> items;
    private TextView text;
    private ImageButton include;

    public SuggestionAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, List<String> items)
    {
        super(context, cursor, false);

        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        text.setText(items.get(cursor.getPosition()));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suggestion_item, parent, false);

        text    = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.suggestion_item);
        include = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.suggestion_include);

        return view;
    }
}
```

**Suggestion Item XML**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/suggestion_bottom_border"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/suggestion_item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorMediumText"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/suggestion_include"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_call_made_black"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So, what I want to do is listen whether it's clicked on the textview, or the ImageButton. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SuggestionAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{
    private List<String> items;
    private TextView text;
    private ImageButton include;

    public SuggestionAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, List<String> items)
    {
        super(context, cursor, false);

        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        text.setText(items.get(cursor.getPosition()));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suggestion_item, parent, false);

        text    = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.suggestion_item);
        include = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.suggestion_include);

        return view;
    }
}


public class Filter extends Activity{


searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
    {
        if (Utils.isQueryOk(query))
        {
            ....
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
    {
        if (newText.length() > 1)
        {
            new getSuggestionsFromServer().execute(newText);
        } 

        return true;
    }
});

private class getSuggestionsFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    List<String> suggestions;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        // Retrieve suggestions from server

        return null;
    }

}


Implemet Suggesion Adapter within the Filter Activity
```

Comment: Please, can you elaborate more your answer?