# How implement the Google Play like search bar

Tags: android, material-design, searchbar

I need to implement a search in my app and it should look like this

[image: Google play store search bar]

would someone please care enough to explain to me how its done.?? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can read about it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing SearchView in action bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom layout for that.
1. take a relative layout and give it a rounded bordered background to it.
2. add hamburger icon to left in it. 
3. add mic icon to right in it.
4. Add edittext to it in the center.
and then handle to click on both hamburger icon and mic icon manually.

I have some code which is not exactly same but you can edit and change it accordingly.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/editext_border">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_search_mic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_green" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ed_home_searchbar"
                fontPath="fonts/weblysleekuisl.ttf"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_search_icon"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_search_mic"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="@string/action_search"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_xxsmall" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_search_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search_green" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

and then handle the click event like open google voice search on mic click

```
searchMic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OnSwap.getInstance().trackEvent(TAG, "searchMic", "searchMic Clicked");
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Search");
                startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_INPUT_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
```

and then onActivityResult method

```
if (requestCode == VOICE_INPUT_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                        RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                int matchSize = matches.size();
                for (int index = 0; index < matchSize; index++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(index) + ": " + matches.get(index));
                    if (index == 0) {
                        searchbar.setText(matches.get(index));
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());
                Snackbar.make(locationTextView, status.getStatusMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Snackbar.make(locationTextView, "Canceled", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thnks mate.... i was going no where following few online docs on this search thing.

Comment: Happy to help buddy :)