# Cloning the Google Play search bar / edittext and toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, searchview

I want to clone the Google Play search bar.
I was wondering how can i achieve that using toolbar and edit text's

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/toolbar" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"  >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/searchEditText" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How implement the Google Play like search bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787001/how-implement-the-google-play-like-search-bar)