# Android search framework

Tags: android, android-search

I am using the search manager of android to display data from my server when typing in the searchView. The problem is when displaying images in The SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1 it blocks the application and I can't find how to make them download in background and get the result to update the cursor.

- I already created a ContentProvider
- Declare it in manifest.xml
- Configured the searchable.xml
- Displayed data

I'm only having problem with images. They took a while to be displayed.
Any Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find how to make them download in background

you can use third party libraries for this purpose such as [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso).

they take image url and download it in background and show them on UI thread and you can configure them to match your needs

Comment: I'm already using Glide, the problem is that I had to download the image and then get it as a file from the cache because SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1 is a predefined resource in android and it only 3 formats available for displaying the image

Comment: a local file or a content uri or a local resource, it can't be shown directly from the URL

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that I don't need the content provider for my app, so I removed it, and I just used the `OnQueryTextListener` on the `SearchView` with a custom adapter for suggestions.
So everything works fine now, instant search with asynchronous images show.

[This answer helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar?answertab=votes#tab-top)

[image]