# Using Search in App Bar to Query in a fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, search, android-navigation

So basically I'm developing an app with a navigation bar and tabbed layout with a search icon added in the app bar. each of the tabs has a listview.
Please give me an Idea on how to use the search to query in a fragment like this.

[image]

Comment: Please provide what you already have tried.

Comment: I deleted the code because it stops my app from running. Maybe I'll just try to make the searchview visible when the search icon is clicked. and follow the codes on some sample app with searchview.

Comment: Use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar

Comment: It's hard to tell without anything to rely on. Have you already checked this Android guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html ?

Comment: suggestions are noted. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getActivity(). getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
            {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query)
            {
               // pass query to your filter 
                return true;
            }

        });
    }
```