# How To Add Action Bar in All Activity

Tags: android

I want to add my ActionBar in all of my activities and then the FloatingActionButton as well. How can I do that?

Here is my main activity

```
SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Comment: Tool bar can be included in all XML files or you can create one base Activity and extend it everywhere you want

Comment: I have a tileview library so how can I extend it cause my second activity it have extends TileViewActivity. sorry for my english

Comment: I have posted answer to this question please check.

Comment: yes you can try that. may be that activity will have toolbar implementation.

Answer (score 1):

you can create one base activity :-

```
 public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  Toolbar toolbar;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutResource());
    configureToolbar();
  }

  protected abstract int getLayoutResource();

  private void configureToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
  }
}
```

and you can extend this base activity :-

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {


     @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      }

      @Override
      public int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Im using tileview how can i use "extends base activity" in my second activity cause it have a "extends TileViewActivity ". sorry for my english

Comment: this is the approach may be TileViewActivity will have toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Write these lines in your Second activity in  OnCreate Method:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
```

Comment: In my second activity it have "extends TileViewActivity" the codes is not AppCompatActivity cause im using tileview library. the codes you provide is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.Activity"
        android:label="Main"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
```

And in style.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: the code that you provide is working but i Have i SearchView in my ActionBar how can I add that?

Comment: <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>

Comment: check this tooo   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585326/implementing-searchview-in-action-bar